# The site I'm trying to access blocks Tor, what can I do?

Tags: censorship

I'm trying to access a site, but it blocks Tor, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways. If you're trying to access for example www.example.com and it blocks Tor then you may,

1. Search for it in startpage.com, and then use the "Proxy" button which will redirect you to that site as accessed from one of the proxy servers of startpage
2. Use web.archive.org/save/_embed/www.example.com, not only would you save the URL for future generations, but you will also have the ability to see the page.
3. Use a web proxy, such as: https://hide.me/en/proxy

**All of these approaches may be non-convenient, but that's better than nothing.**

Ultimately the best way is to contact the site's administrators to let them know that they're blocking legitimate requests to their site.